# Pass results of Conditional Split to stored procedure

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

We are reading in data from two OLE DB data sources, sorting each and then merging them.  We then perform a Conditional Split to place the data into three "buckets".  We next want to pass each resulting record set to each one's appropriate stored procedure.  There are several columns in the results.

Snapshot of SSIS flow:

[image]

- How can we best pass these rows to the SP?
- Should this be done in the Data Flow or as another step in the Control Flow?

Answer (score 0):

Pass rows to a Stored Procedure via an [OLEDB Command Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/ole-db-command-transformation?view=sql-server-2017).

And yes, you do this in the dataflow, not another step in the control flow.

Comment: Tried that path and got roadblocked trying to map the results to the parameters of the stored procedure.

Comment: Then you should either edit, or ask another question and show us the "roadblock" you got so we can help debug it.    Look at steps 12 and 13 in the article I linked in my answer.